# wcf service on load balance

Tags: c#, wcf, load-balancing

We have a windows application and it consumes WCF sevice and we use Network Load balancing.Sometimes clients could not connect to wcf service(server).
we use `NetTcpBinding` binding. Can anyone give me an idea to solve this issue.

Comment: How easily repeatable is the problem?

Comment: sorry,i didn't got what you say

Comment: Could you set up a client and make that fail, or does it happen so seldom that it's hard to repeat?

Comment: it happens frequently but i don't know to make it fail

Comment: I'd start by putting [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) on a client and make it log until the client fails. Also, log all error info you can get to on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your bindings here?

I would turn on tracing in your web service config to check that traffic is indeed reaching all your intended endpoints. NetTcpBinding pools TCP connections by default, so it could be that the client connection has associated itself to a specific server which is now not available. This would then mean that connections would start to fail. It is recommended that you tweak the default binding settings for NetTcpBinding when used in a load balanced scenario to reduce the lease timeout so that requests are load balanced better. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730128.aspx